# How to search records which have at least one of the columns having null or no value?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to search for records among a list of columns where at least one of the columns having null value or no value. I used the sql below but it only returned the records with null value but not the ones with no value.

select firstname, lastname, address1, address2, postcode from table where firstname + lastname + address1 + address2 + postcode = null

Thanks for your time in advance :)

Comment: You can select against empty string '' or check the length of the value using the DATALENGTH function

Comment: I tried to do where  firstname + lastname + address1 + address2 + postcode = '' but it did not return the correct value. Do I have to do where firstname = '' or lastname = '' or address1 = '' or address2 = '' or postcode = ''? Is there a better way to do it if there is much longer list of columns? Thanks.

Comment: Yes in general I would say putting the condition for each column is going to be your best option here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select firstname, lastname, address1, address2, postcode 
from table 
where isnull(firstname,'')='' or  isnull(lastname,'') ='' or  isnull(address1,'') ='' or  isnull(address2,'')='' or  isnull(postcode,'')) =''
```